# Searching for all sentences containing a string in another document

Tags: python, string-matching

I have a file containing 200 words, each on a new line.
I want to search for all these words in another file. I want each sentence containing one of these words to be printed.
Right now, only the matches of the first word appear. After that, it stops.

```
corpus = open('C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\HAIT\\Scriptie\\Tweet-corpus\\Corpus.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')

with open('C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\HAIT\\Scriptie\\Tweet-corpus\\MostCommon3.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as list:
for line in list:
    for a in corpus:
        if line in a:
            print(a)
```

Comment: FYI, you should avoid re-using built-ins functions, like `list`, as variables within your code.

Comment: `corpus` is a file object.  The first time through the outer loop, the inner `for a in corpus:` loop reads the entire file.  On all subsequent iterations of the outer loop, `corpus` is still at end-of-file, so the inner loop never enters its body.  That's why only the first `line` has any chance of matching.  You could, e.g., read `corpus` into a list of its lines (`.readlines()`), and iterate over that list instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Prepare the list of words
word_file = open('wordfile', 'r', encoding='utf8')
words = [word.strip() for word in word_file.readlines()]
word_file.close()

# Now examine each sentence:
with open('sentencefile') as sentences:
    for sentence in sentences:
        found = False
        for word in words:
            if word in sentence:
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            print sentence
```